# How to Insert Data from multiple tables into one

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, t-sql

I am trying to insert data into a table using data from 2 other tables.

I need to use:

`Project.ProjectID` and `Action.ActionID` to be inserted into a table I have called

`ActionDetails, WHERE the Project.ProjectID = 1`

Any ideas...? i've googled everywhere with no success :(

Comment: If you would be so kind to post the code you've already written I'm sure help will be forthcoming

Comment: I think the question is not clear,  Can you please provide more information please/

Answer (score 1):

You have actions from a template, that you need to add to ActionDetails after creating a new Project?  Try this

```
Insert ActionDetails (ProjectID, ActionID)
select P.ProjectId, A.ActionID
from Project P
inner join Action A on A.templateID = 1  -- or some condition on A
WHERE P.ProjectID = 1
```

If the action table contains just a single list to be added to all projects, use a cross join instead

```
Insert ActionDetails (ProjectID, ActionID)
select P.ProjectId, A.ActionID
from Project P cross join Action A
WHERE P.ProjectID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

only if the table is not yet created it will create the table for you

```
select  P.ProjectId,                       
                A.ActionID 
        into [NEW_TABLE]                                                                                      
        from Project P 
        inner join [Action] A --jOINING THE TWO TABLES 
        WHERE P.ProjectID = 1
```

Comment: Significant typo you might want to fix: int [NEW_TABLE] should be INTO [NEW_TABLE]. You're missing the O in INTO